# Install HEIC Supported imagick extension in cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel, centos7, imagick, amazon-lightsail

I have installed and tested php native imagick extension locally. Module version is  3.7.0. it support HEIC. But within the cPanel, I have installed it through PECL installer. Same version installed but it's not supported HEIC format.

PHP version - 8.0
OS - CentOS v7.9.2009 STANDARD xen hvm
Cpanel version - 106.0.10

I have root access and terminal access in amazon LightSail instance.

I removed old imagick version and installed it again through remi repository. But the result was same. I want to install HEIC supported PHP imagick extension to the server.

Comment: You forgot to ask any question. Also, as this does not look related to programming to me, it might be more on-topic on serverfault.com

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I removed old imagick version and installed it again through remi repository. But the result was same.
> I want to install HEIC supported PHP imagick extension to the server.

Using **remi** repository, HEIC support comes from ImageMagick in the "heic" optional sub-package.

You need to install, for new version 7:

- php-pecl-imagick-im7
- ImageMagick7-libs, required by previous
- ImageMagick7-heic
- libheif, from [RPMfusion](https://rpmfusion.org/), required by previous

Or (for old version 6)

- php-pecl-imagick-im6
- ImageMagick6-libs, required by previous
- ImageMagick6-heic
- libheif, from [RPMfusion](https://rpmfusion.org/), required by previous

Also read:

- [ImageMagick6 and ImageMagick7](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2016/12/12/ImageMagick6-and-ImageMagick7)
- [HEIC / HEIF images support](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2019/05/22/HEIC-HEIF-images-support)

And for a proper repository configuration / usage, follow the [wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)